# Unused regex captures in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, string, block

I have a script that processes the contents of a file from a CAD program, for use in another CAD program. Can the unused variables in the block be skipped, or written around? The script works fine with them in place, I was just curious if there was a cleaner way to write it. Thank you.

```
    string = IO.read("file.txt")

    string.scan(/regex/m) {|a,b,c,d,e,f,g|

    # captures 7 items, I use 1-4, & 6 below, skipping 5 & 7

    print a, b+".ext", c.to_f/25400000, d.to_f/25400000, f,"\n"
    }
```

My question lies in the last line - if I'm not using them all - do I still have to declare them all, for it to work properly, and remain in the correct order?

Elements 5 & 7 may be used at a later time, but for now, they are just part of the regex, for future flexibility.

Comment: @Mark, you changed my title in order to more accurately represent my question - however, I believe my mistake was in not using the term "parameter", as that is what I was inquiring about. Scripts can have several unused regex captures, and more often that not, they usually do. I'm not going to change it, but for clarification's sake, my specific curiosity was about "Unused parameters in a block". i.e... e & g were assigned, but never called. Does that make sense? If not, please advise, I don't want to confuse anyone that may get directed here, thanks ;-)

Comment: yes, those parameters are regex captures in block form. I'm sure it could have been put any number of ways. Feel free to edit it again.

Comment: @Mark: I'm good with the way it is - our comments are enough, to kick it out in a search engine. That's all I was really worried about anyway - personally, I can't stand sifting through 100's of search results, for the wrong thing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array instead of an explicit list of variables and then pick things out of the array by index:

```
string.scan(/regex/m) { |a|
    print a[0], a[1] + ".ext", a[2].to_f / 25400000, a[3].to_f / 25400000, a[5], "\n"
}
```

Either that or rework your regular expression to only capture what you need.

You can use the same variable multiple times in the list so just renaming the things you're not using to `unused` would probably be the simplest choice:

```
string.scan(/regex/m) { |a, b, c, d, unused, f, unused|
    print a, b + ".ext", c.to_f / 25400000, d.to_f / 25400000, f, "\n"
}
```

At least this way it is (or should be) obvious that you're not using the fifth and seventh captures. However, this doesn't work in 1.9 so you'd have to use `unused1` and `unused2` in 1.9.

An ideal balance would be to use 1.9's named capture groups but `scan` doesn't give you access to them.

Comment: Your first is example is closer to what I was trying to do accomplish from the get go, but I kept getting 'NoMethodError's, trying to capture the file as an array, via scan. It looks more elegant too - so now I can just add 'a[5]' and 'a[7]', if I decide to use them later (w/o modifying the regex) - thank you ;-)

Comment: @tahwos: The problem with using an array is that it separates the source of the indexes (i.e. the capture groups in the regex) from where the indexes are used and that's a bit error prone. The second approach keeps it all together and is more maintainable. I think a slightly ugly but maintainable solution is far superior to an elegant yet brittle solution.

Comment: I found that out the hard way - either I wasn't separating them enough, or I was separating them too much. I wish I could vote twice on your first example - as it fits nicely in my original script, which used IO.readlines(file).split, to process a much simpler text file.

Comment: thanks for the additional info about 1.9... I'm getting really used to 1.8.6, and from what I hear, 1.8.7 on up is a different ballgame for a lot of things, especially once you get past 1.9. This kinda makes me leery of even exploring it, out of fear that I'll have to re-learn everything that already works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are getting the variables as block variables, you cannot skip the order. The problem is with your regex. If you have a group that you don't want to capture, you should use the uncapturing group `(?: )` instead of the capturing group `( )`. So change the fifth and the seventh `( )` in your regex to `(?: )`. If you are using ruby 1.9 or are using oniguruma regex engine on ruby 1.8.7, then you can also use named captures; for example use `(?<foo> )` in the regex, and refer to the captured string in the block as `foo` or `$~[:foo]`.

Comment: I'm actually using 1.8.6, due to limitations of the receiving application. The script will be run from inside the receiving application, to import the file from another application. Coincidentally, I'm using the regex you gave me in another post - it works flawlessly as is, and is portable to other variables within the document, just by remaining the match criteria. In other words, it needs to remain intact - your first sentence answered my question "no, I can't" - thank you ;-)